# Is it C-3PO or C-3P0?

Tags: star-wars, c-3po

A lot of people will interchange an "o" for a zero when speaking them aloud, like with phone numbers and postal codes, so I'm thinking this is the same here, but with nicknames like "threepio", I'm not so sure.

I'm looking for the canon answer here.

Comment: Google certainly thinks its "C-3PO" (O for Orange, not 0 for the balance of my bank account).

Comment: It always bothered me that they were 4 character serial numbers. That doesn't add up to very many unique droid names.

Comment: @Sobrique I always assumed (for my own sanity) that they were the head or tail of a longer serial code. Much like git tags are frequently reduced to only a few characters instead of the full hash.

Comment: See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22658/is-there-only-one-r2-d2-droid-in-the-galaxy-or-were-other-r2-d2-droids-made for more discussion on droid naming conventions

Comment: @Sobrique actually, it's a five digit serial number. The dash itself is a character. Notice C-3PO vs. R2-D2, the dash is in a different place. And some types of droids had much longer names/codes.

Comment: Also see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/55876/19561 for more musings about C-3PO's name.

Comment: @Sobrique I always thought they were model names, not serial numbers; i.e. there could be many C-3POs.

Comment: @agweber And of course people even shorten those short designations, much like how my friends shorten "fluffy" (which is my real-life nickname) to "fluffs." Or sometimes lengthen it to "flufferson" for some reason.

Comment: @smci While the canonicity of The Phantom Menace is debated, in that movie they refer to R2-D2 as being the designation of that specific unit at the end.

Comment: @fluffy thanks, but the only place I want to see *The Phantom Menace* is in the stomach of a Sarlacc Beast.

Comment: @Omegacron: I can only agree with that by 50%. Yes, in its written form, it's a five digit serial number, but unless we have *heard* droid names being *spoken* like see-dash-three-pee-oh or ar-two-dash-dee-two, we should assume that the dash is somehow considered irrelevant for identification by the people of a galaxy far, far way.

Comment: I was about to ask this exact question. +1

Comment: I don't see a canon answer however since R2D2 goes Letter, number,letter number, if you apply the same format to C3P0, then the last character is a zero and people simply call it o because it's easier (which is incorrectly propagated by future writers of the series itself)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html) spells it with an 'O':

> An explosion rocks the ship as two robots, Artoo-Detoo (R2-D2) and See-Threepio (C-3PO) struggle to make their way through the shaking, bouncing passageway. Both robots are old and battered. Artoo is a short, claw-armed tripod. His face is a mass of computer lights surrounding a radar eye. Threepio, on the other hand, is a tall, slender robot of human proportions. He has a gleaming bronze-like metallic surface of an Art Deco design.
>
> <sup><sub>[**Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope** (1977)](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html)</sub></sup>

Although I can't find his designation used anywhere in the *text* of the novelization, the 1979 paperback has an inset featuring stills from the movie and short character bios; Threepio's designation appears there as "C-3PO" (with an 'O', not a '0'):

[image: A faded scan of an old book]

It's faded, but you can clearly see an 'O'.

Comment: Although I think you're right, where's the evidence that that's a O in that font and not a 0?

Comment: @ThePopMachine While I can't be certain, the font appears to be either Futura or Twentieth Century, which have very distinctive O and 0 characters. The capital O in these fonts have an equal width and height.

Comment: "Threepio" - now that raises the question of why it's not pronounced "three - pie - oh" instead of "three-pee-oh".

Answer (score 33):

**StarWars.com, the scripts,  and the novelization all explicitly say it is C-3PO.**

To confirm this, I copy-pasted the text from the [StarWars.com page](http://www.starwars.com/databank/c-3po) shown below and then typed it out with a zero instead in a font that distinguishes the two characters. You can see the difference in fonts.

> "C-3PO" – directly from starwars.com
>
> "C-3P0" – typed with a zero-character

[image: threepio]

Similarly to this, I checked the novelization and the scripts. Searching for "C-3PO" returns numerous results. Searching for "C-3P0" returns none.

Comment: Another piece of evidence is that the URL on StarWars.com actually uses a lower-case 'o', which is clearly not a zero.